How to Identify pins connected to each other?
There is probably another way to achieve what I want without connecting pins to each other, so I will explain the scenario:
I am trying to build an Arduino based Enigma Machine. The cryptography is working fine, it runs from the serial monitor. Now I want to make the interface more real.
The original machine has a plugboard: 26 terminals (labeled from A to Z) where you can connect a cable from one letter to another, and the user can make up to 10 of these connections.
I am stuck in this part. How could I do it electronically? How to tell the microcontroller if a pin is connected to any other pin?
If I assign each terminal to a separated pin on the board, I can't have these pins in output and input mode at the same time.
My first idea was to make an array of resistors to make uniques associations and read the different analog values, but it is impractical.
I also tried to draw a logic circuit to read exact associations, but also doesn't work.
I know it can be done with an Arduino Mega, as there are replicas being sold online based on this board. Is there any other hardware suitable for the situation? I wiil be glad to hear.

How to tell to the microcontroller if a pin is conected to any other pin? ... you don't have to tell it anything ... the microcontroller can detect connections between pins

I cant have these pins in output and input mode at same time ... just set only one as output

If you have enough pins for all 26 terminals, you can directly through all connection iteratively:

Set all pins to INPUT_PULLUP
Set one pin to OUTPUT and LOW
Read all pins beside that one output pin and check, if one reads LOW (meaning connection between output pin and this one)
Repeat for all pins (each pin being an output pin in one iteration)

You could save this in an array of 26 ints. The position in the array would be the "start pin" of the connection, the value would be the target pin.
With the above algorithm you of course get each connection twice. Either just ignore the second one in whatever you are doing with the data, or you can check, if that pin already got a connection and set it's value to -1 (meaning "not important/not needed").
If you don't have enough pins, you can use a multiplexer, where you can connect multiple terminals to one pin on the Arduino, one at a time, iterating again over very terminal.

I think it is useful having at position X mapping to Y and at position Y mapping to X

Thanks for the answer, but this way is also impractical, as it has to work in a real machine.
For example, if I grab a cable and connect one end on the pin 1, and then I grab another cable and connect to the pin 2, I will have two loose ends. If I connect the first end of the first cable on the pin3, in this moment the Arduino wouldnt be able to know if the connection is 1-3 or 2-3.

@DiegoDyan yes, it would know, that the connection is between pin1 and pin3, since that connection would result in a pulled to LOW pin 1 and pin 3. The other cable does nothing, since it is connected only at one side, which is electrically the same as connecting nothing in this case. So in your scenario the second cable (which is connected only on one side) could just as well not be there. Only the connection, that forms a circuit (by connecting two pins) is relevant. So I don't see, where the problem would be.

I think you are right. In my head, the trigger to start the iteration would be the first connection, but not necessarily is.
I simulated it with less pins in ThinkerCad and it kind of works. The code needs some fine tuning to return the exact parameter, but the answer is useful. Thank you very much.
